# Using the Mean Value Theorem to Prove an Inequality involving the second derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Consider the twice-differentiable function $f$ such that $f(0) = 0$, $f(1/2) = 1/2$, and $f'(0) = 0$. Prove that $f''(x)$ is greater than or equal to 4 for some $x$ in the domain $[0, 1/2]$.

NOTE: Please don't just use one example of a possible function for $f$ and solve it using that example as I want to be able to generalize it to all cases.

EDIT: Sorry if it wasn't clear - the question is asking to prove that the second derivative of $f(x)$ ($f''(x)$) is greater than or equal to 4. I've tried solving for $f'(x)$ from $f(0)$ and $f(1/2)$, and then trying to disprove a counterexample to the inequality we are given (trying to prove that $f''(x)$ cannot be less than 4), but that's as far as I've gotten.

EDIT2: I've just realized that the question did not ask for all x, but only some x. This was a huge mistake on my part, so I'm extremely sorry to all those who have helped thus far.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. If $f'(0) = 0$, then how can it be true that $f'(x) \ge 4$ for all $x \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$? Also, once that is resolved, please update the question text to show what you've tried so far (as dfnu has also asked) and, in particular, indicate anything you had particular difficulty with. Thanks.

Comment: I think OP wants the second derivative $\geq 4$. But that is also false.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for your comment. The text made it look like just a single derivative, but you're right.

Comment: Since $4x^3$ is a very obvious counter example, most probably the requirements for $f$ in your exercise are not complete. Or, the exercise is nonsense.

Comment: trancelocation- how is that a counterexample? 4x^3 is completely valid when you use x=1/2, is it not?

Comment: @fluorous $f''(x) = 24x$. Hence, for $0\leq x < \frac{1}{6}$ you have $0 \leq f''(x) < 4$. Since, $[0,\frac{1}{6}] \subset [0,\frac{1}{2}]$, the claim that $f''(x) \geq 4$ for all $x \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$ cannot be true.

Comment: @trancelocation check edit, sorry about that

Comment: @fluorous: Added a solution that shows that there must be a $\xi \in (0,\frac{1}{2})$ where $f''(\xi) = 4$.

Comment: @trancelocation thank you so much! sorry to waste your time with the mistake in wording

Answer (score 0):

Th question has been modified.

Answer for the old version:

This is not true. If $f(x)=8x^{4}$ then all the conditions are satisfied but $f''(x) <4$ when $x$ is close to $0$.

Comment: How can we consider this valid when it doesn't satisfy the inequality for the whole domain?

Comment: @fluorous which one of your *hypotheses* do you think this function does not satisfy?

Comment: @dfnu "but ″()<4 when  is close to 0."

Comment: @fluorous this is actually the negation of your *thesis*. This example, as the others, all satisfy the hypotheses you gave, but do have some points $x$ in $[0,1/2]$ for which $f''(x) \leq 4$, which makes your thesis false.

Answer (score 0):

Another funny counterexample

$$f(x) =\begin{cases} 4x^3\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4x}\right) & (x\neq 0) \\ 0 & (x=0)\end{cases}.$$

Concavity changes infinitely many times in any neighborhood of $0$, thus $f''(x)$ takes on both positive and negative values in $[0,1/2]$.

Comment: oh my i just realized it's not for all x, just some x

Answer (score 0):

Solution for your edited question:

According to Taylor you have for $x \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$

$$f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + \frac{1}{2}f''(\xi_x)x^2 = \frac{1}{2}f''(\xi_x)x^2$$

with $\xi_x \in (0, x)$.

For $x= \frac{1}{2}$ you have
$$\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}f''(\xi_{\frac{1}{2}})\frac{1}{4} \Rightarrow f''(\xi_{\frac{1}{2}}) = 4$$